# OpenGL Depth buffer in orthographic projection

Tags: opengl, depth-buffer

If I use orthographic projection in OpenGL, but still set different z-values to my objects, does it still be visible in Depth Buffer?

I mean, in color buffer everything looks plain and at one distance. But wherever they will "colorized" in different shades? Does depth buffer "understand" depth in  orthographic projection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A depth buffer has nothing to do with the projection matrix. Simply put, a z-buffer takes note of the closest Z-value at a given point. As things are drawn it looks at the current value. If the new value is less then the existing value it is accepted and the z buffer is updated. If the value is greater then the value, behind the current value, it is discarded. The depth buffer has nothing to do with color. I think you might be confusing blending with depth testing.

For example, say you have two quads A & B.

A.z =  - 1.0f;

B.z =  - 2.0f;

If you assume that both quads have the same dimensions, outside of their Z value, then you can see how drawing both would be a waste. Since quad A is in front of quad B it is a waste to draw quad B. What the depth buffer does is checks the zcords. In this example if you had enabled depth testing & a depth buffer quad B would never have been drawn because the depth testing would have shown it was occluded by quad A.

Comment: So if the one not hides another, in depth buffer, one be lighter and another darker (if look it as greyscale)?

Comment: @tower120 That depends on a lot of factors. For starters, what is the alpha value of the overlaying object? More importantly, what is blend testing enabled and what blend functions are being used? You would need to answer those questions before I could give you an answer to that.

Comment: @tower120 Sorry, I think I misunderstood your question. Are you asking how the depth buffer would appear? There would be no blending at all. The entire object would be the same "shade of gray". What I think you're asking about is what shade the object gets. Well, thats based on the depth buffer, but normally the closer you are the darker your color while the farther away is a softer shade of gray (in the depth buffer).

Comment: Objects(simple triangles) are completely opaque. One Object have z = 1, another z = 2. Does 1st triangle will be the same color/index in the depth buffer as the 2nd?

Comment: No - because the depth component us different.